# regex .findall() doesn't return all matches

Tags: python-2.7

I tried to find a keyword and select sentences surrounding the keyword. The input text (for example) is as follows. I made the keyword bold for explanatory purpose:

> The Board of Directors has adopted Corporate Governance Guidelines, a copy of which is available on our Internet website at www.henryschein.com, under the Corporate Information-Corporate Governance caption. Our Corporate Governance Guidelines address topics such as (i) role of the Board of Directors, (ix) management development and **succession planning**, (xiv) submission of director resignations and (xv) communicating with the Board of Directors.
>
> Among other things, the Company’s Corporate Governance Guidelines provide that it is the Board of Directors’ policy to periodically review issues related to the selection and performance of the Chief Executive Officer. At least annually, the Chief Executive Officer must report to the Board of Directors on the Company’s program for management development and on **succession planning**. In addition, the Board of Directors and Chief Executive Officer shall periodically discuss the Chief Executive Officer’s recommendations as to a successor in the event of the sudden resignation, retirement or disability of the Chief Executive Officer.

The code I used is as follows:

```
def find_sentences(text):
    p = re.compile(r'[^\.]*\.[^\.]*succession-planning[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.')
    p2 = re.findall(p,text)

    if len(p2)>1:
        p3 = '######################################'.join(i for i in p2)
    else:
        p3 = p2[0]
    return p3

text2 = re.sub(r'succession planning[^\s^\w+]+','succession-planning', text)
sentence=find_sentences(text2)
```

The output is as follows:

> The Board of Directors has adopted Corporate Governance Guidelines, a copy of which is available on our Internet website at www.henryschein.com, under the Corporate Information-Corporate Governance caption. Our Corporate Governance Guidelines address topics such as (i) role of the Board of Directors, (ix) management development and **succession planning**, (xiv) submission of director resignations and (xv) communicating with the Board of Directors.
>
> Among other things, the Company’s Corporate Governance Guidelines provide that it is the Board of Directors’ policy to periodically review issues related to the selection and performance of the Chief Executive Officer.

**Question:** the problem is when I print **`p2`** above, it only returns sentences surrounding and including the first succession planning. It does not return the second incurrence of that keyword. I need a code to return the following in addition to the above output:

> Among other things, the Company’s Corporate Governance Guidelines provide that it is the Board of Directors’ policy to periodically review issues related to the selection and performance of the Chief Executive Officer. At least annually, the Chief Executive Officer must report to the Board of Directors on the Company’s program for management development and on **succession planning**. In addition, the Board of Directors and Chief Executive Officer shall periodically discuss the Chief Executive Officer’s recommendations as to a successor in the event of the sudden resignation, retirement or disability of the Chief Executive Officer.

When I changed **`p`** with `p = re.compile(r'[^\.]*succession-planning[^\.]*\.')`, it returns both incurrences, but do not include surrounding sentences. I think findall doesn't return the overlapped matches. How can I make them returned?

Comment: you might want to read about non-greedy versions of the * regex-operator. The tail needs that.

Comment: Unless you are doing this as a regular expression exercise, if your goal is to replace `succession planning` with `succession-planning`, you can simply do a `replace('succession planning', 'succession-planning')`.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer: `.findall()`** method returns all matches.

`.findall()` method cannot return any match on a text, which **does not contain** the designed phrase-segment ( there is no such sub-string == "**succession-planning**" )

```
p = re.compile(r'[^\.]*\.[^\.]*succession-planning[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.')
```

Yes, there are "almost-similar" segments, but without "**`-`**"

**Resume:** regex is not to be blamed not to find a text-segment, that is not present at all.

---

The second "succession planning"-*keyword* inclusion ( or not inclusion ) is **not** dependent of `re.findall()` method, but **is** dependent on a strictness of the Task Definition requirement, which states "**surrounding** the keyword".

**A weak interpretation** may include a case, where right-side of the *keyword* is not "**surrounded**" by any sentence continuation words, but terminated by a pull-stop sign.

**A strong interpretation** will restrict such case as failing to be **surrounded** on both sides of the *keyword*.

```
>>> mStrg = re.compile( r'....succession planning[^\.]+?\.[^\.]*?\.' )
>>> mWeak = re.compile( r'....succession planning[^\.]*?\.' )
>>> re.findall( mWeak, text )
[ "...", "...for management development and on succession planning."]
>>> len( re.findall( mWeak, text ) )
2
```